# Issues with wrapping PrismForms NavigationService

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, platform-independent, navigationservice

In PrismForms we got the problem, that the NavigationStack is empty after navigating to a new page. That means after using the hardware back-button on the SecondPage, the app is closed. Although the back-arrow in the header on Android isnt shown. If looking closely you can see the back-arrow for a short moment after the page is switched. I guess thats before the NavigationStack gets cleared.

To the first page we navigate with the following command in OnInitialized() in our App.xaml.cs which derives from PrismApplication.

```
    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/StartPage");
```

(If only Navigating to „StartPage“ here, the Stack doesnt get cleared.)

That has do to with PageNavigationService.ProcessNavigationForNavigationPage(...) calling
        bool clearNavStack = GetClearNavigationPageNavigationStack(currentPage); and PageNavigationService.ProcessNavigationForContentPage(...) not.

From the StartPage to the next we navigate with NavigateAsync("SecondPage")“. Here the described behaviour appears.

For navigation we use a class which wraps the Prism NavigationService. We hold him as a property and get him via Unity in our constructor:

```
    this.PrismNavigation = prismNavigation ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(prismNavigation));
```

The methods „NavigateAsync“ and „GoBackAsync“, etc. we just pass through.

This way we want to seperate our ViewModel-Project from references to XamarinForms to later be able to use the same ViewModels for for example a WPF-GUI.

Why is the stack beeing cleared by our own NavigationService? If we register the original Prism NavigationService in App.xaml.cs instead, navigating back works as expected again. We found the point in the framework and could avoid the clearing with a drity hack, but that’s against the navigation-logic implemented in PrismForms, but we don’t understand how to do it the correct way.

Every help appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you have an exception being thrown when either the View or ViewModel is being resolved. You might try resolving your ViewModels and Page's within a try/catch before your navigate, and log the exception.

Comment: We will try that and report back later. Thanks for the first ideas Dan.

Comment: That was not the case. Everything could be resolved well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We edited a few things to get it working after finding some interesting information by Brian Lagunas in the forlast-post here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/591

Although the topic was about something else, it led to improvements for overwriting the Navigation Service.

Remember that in your viewModels the Navigation Service must be named "navigationService" by convention. Also we switched from just holding the Prism Navigation Service as a parameter to deriving from it as suggested in the link above.

```
    public class MyNavigationService : UnityPageNavigationService
```